# What is the best way to store e-mail accounts data used for sending mailing to customers in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, sendmail

I'm using PEAR::Mail to send a lot of e-mails to our customers. I want to be able to send those e-mails using different SMTP accounts (because of different mailing types). We have like 6-7 accounts, and in the future there might be more. Each of them has different password and we want to be able to store those passwords in database so it's not hardcoded and so you can add them more easily with administrator panel.

I know I want to use encryption for password storing, but imo hashing is not an option here. I want to be able to read those passwords, not only compare the hashes.

I would like to do it with storing encrypted passwords in database but encrypt them with some algorithm. And that's where I have problem - I don't know much about that. I'm attaching my test code for encryption, but I would like your opinion on how should I improve it:

```
if (!function_exists('hex2bin')) {

    function hex2bin($data) {
        $len = strlen($data);
        return pack('H' . $len, $data);
    }

}

$key = $_GET['key'];
$text = $_GET['text'];
$encr = $_GET['encr'];

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

if ($text != null) {
    echo bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
}

if ($encr != null) {
    echo mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, hex2bin($encr), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECB mode is insecure and the IV is ignored with this mode. You should really use CBC (MCRYPT_MODE_CBC) instead.

When using CBC an IV is required for encryption and the same IV is required for decryption, so you need to hang on to this value (but don't use the same IV for all encryption/decryption, generating a random one as in your code example is correct). The IV does not need to be stored securely (any more securely than the encrypted data), and it's standard proceedure to prepend the IV to the encrypted data.

```
bin2hex($iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
```

When decrypting you strip off the IV and pass it in to mcrypt_decrypt.

```
$cipherTextDecoded = hex2bin($encr);
$iv = substr($cipherTextDecoded, 0, $iv_size);
$cipherText = substr($cipherTextDecoded, $iv_size);
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $cipherText, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Also note that you should be using a binary key. `$_GET['key']` is returning a string of text, and because you're not hex decoding it your keyspace is limited to all possible 256-bit strings rather than all 256-bit binary values.

Further, it's a bit misleading in PHP, but the 256 in `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` refers to the block size, not the strength of the encryption. If you want to use 256 bit encryption, just pass a 256 bit key to the `mcrypt` functions. If that was your goal I'd consider using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` instead, this will make the encrypted text compatible with AES-128. If you ever need to decrypt the data in some other system (unlikely I know), it's much easier to find an AES-128 imeplementation than Rijindael 256.

Comment: So do you suggest I should store IV in database with each encrypted password, or should I use your way of prepending the IV to encrypted data and store it in one cell with password?
Thank you very much for your answer, I really appreciate it and it now explained to me what IV is used for (and why did my code worked even though the IV was random each time :P)

Comment: NP. I would prepend the IV. There's no real advantage to storing it in a different location, every encrypted value needs it's own IV, and knowing the value doesn't weaken the encryption on your data at all. Prepending it is standard practice.

Comment: Ok, thank you again. I already implemented it inside a class, can you check my second answer to tell me if I'm doing it alright?

Comment: @KeluThatsall: Added some info about key size after looking at your code.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class which does everything what Syon mentioned. I'm attaching it here for future reference, if anyone would like to use it then feel free.

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('hex2bin')) {
    function hex2bin($data) {
        $len = strlen($data);
        return pack('H' . $len, $data);
    }
}

/**
 * Encipherer - Class used for encoding and decoding
 *
 * @author kelu
 * @version $Id$
 * 
 */
class Encipherer {

    private $key;
    private $iv_size;

    private $mode =         MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
    private $algorithm =    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256;
    private $rand =         MCRYPT_RAND;

    /**
     * returns singleton
     *
     * @return Encipherer
     */
    public static function Instance()
    {
        static $inst = null;
        if ($inst === null) {
            $inst = new Encipherer;
        }
        return $inst;
    }

    private function __construct($key = '') {
        $this->iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->algorithm, $this->mode);
        $this->key = $this->key = hex2bin($key);
    }

    private function __clone()
    {
        return Encipherer::Instance();
    }

    public function setKey($key) {
        $this->key = $this->key = hex2bin($key);
    }

    public function encrypt($text) {
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size, $this->rand);
        return bin2hex($iv . mcrypt_encrypt($this->algorithm, $this->key, $text, $this->mode, $iv));
    }

    public function decrypt($text) {
        $cipherTextDecoded = hex2bin($text);
        $iv = substr($cipherTextDecoded, 0, $this->iv_size);
        $cipherText = substr($cipherTextDecoded, $this->iv_size);
        return mcrypt_decrypt($this->algorithm, $this->key, $cipherText, $this->mode, $iv);
    }
}

?>
```

Example usage:

```
<?
$enc = Encipherer::Instance();
$enc->setKey('1234qwerty');
$encrypted = $enc->encrypt('secret message');
$decrypted = $enc->decrypt($encrypted);
?>
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't use MD5 to derive the key this way. If an attacker knows your key is derived this way, it makes it much easier for them to crack it. I'd generate a completely random key, store it as a hex string, and hex decode it in the `setKey` function. Also note that in php, RIJNDAEL_256 refers to the block size and not the encryption strength. MD5 produces a 128-bit value, so you're using 128 bit encryption in your code (which is fine if that's what you want.) If you want to use 256 bit encryption, you need to feed `mcrypt_encrypt` a 256 bit key.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. How can I generate a random 256 bit key then?

Comment: I'm using hexdec function to decode 256 bit keys. Is that fine now? I'm using keys like this one: 38B93A1BB4EF2BD48AD397DFDEBAC

Comment: You can get a random key from anywhere, it's just random bytes. [Here for example](http://www.random.org/bytes/). For hex decoding use `hex2bin`, so `hex2bin($storedKey)` where `$storedKey = "35ad11 ... 27585f"`.

Comment: So what you mean by that is really, that I want to pass a binary as a key parameter, not a regular string or number?

Comment: Correct, the key should be binary, not a string or number.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the code according to your advices. Thanks a lot again!